# How can I tell if Netbeans 7.3 and Symfony2 is working properly?

Tags: symfony, netbeans, netbeans-7

I have recently followed the common advice found on the internet on how to install Symfony2  in Netbeans 7.3 by pointing the configuration to the Symfony2 standard edition zip file.

Now I'm following the book on the Symfony website to create the HelloBundle demo, and I'm noticing some inconsistencies.

First, when running a Symfony command in Netbeans, the generate bundle does not work as the [book says it should](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html). It forces me to use the --dir option. Here are the parameters I had to add:

```
--namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml  --dir=src
```

Secondly, I see the routing file that was created, but the route parameters are different than what the book says. First the term "Pattern" is used instead of "Path." Further searching indicates that "Pattern" is an obsolete term and that "Path" is preferred now. If this is the case, then why is "Pattern" showing up in my files if I'm using the most current version of the framework (2.3.1)?  Also, my routing file has the word "Default" in it while the book has "Hello." Here is a copy of the output.

```
acme_hello_homepage:
    pattern:  /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeHelloBundle:Default:index }
```

Finally, the book is unclear as to whether or not creating the bundle also automatically creates the controller files. Is this the case? I do not have "HelloController.php" file the books says I should be editing.

I'm new to Symfony, but this feels a little off. If that's the case how do I configure it to work as it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Netbeans as IDE for my symfony 2.x projects, i can't tell what's the problem with your Netbeans configuration, but here's a guide that can help setting-up things :)

http://software-talk.org/blog/2012/06/symfony2-tutorial-netbeans-and-symfony2-setting-everything-up/

Hope it helps.

Comment: ... from that post, "I experienced some problems if I did not place the zip inside the project folder before creating the project, so I would suggest to do it that way."  ... I had left my file in the downloads folder. This was my problem. If yours is working correctly, did you download the zip file to your project folder as well?

Comment: Not inside my project directory, but I use this patterns in my computers to organize my projects folder.
I have a directory named D:\Projects each project is stored in his own directory inside the 'D:\Projects' and the symfony zip is inside D:\Projects.